# Unable to puts in a tcl script

Tags: tcl

I am trying to create a trace function in tcl .Function will list down all the called procs/nested calls and there arguments. Below is the script

```
rename proc _proc
proc proc {nm params body} {
    _proc $nm $params $body
    trace add execution $nm enter [list track_entry $nm $params]
    trace add execution $nm leave [list track_leave $nm]
}
_proc track_entry {nm params real args} {
    puts "Enter proc $nm"
    foreach formal $params actual [lrange $real 1 end] {
        append p " [lindex $formal 0]=$actual,"
    }
    puts "Parameters:$p and body"
}
_proc track_leave {nm args} {
    puts "Exit proc $nm"
}
proc test1 { param1 param2 } {
    puts “parameters are $param1 and $param2”
    test2 value1
}
proc test2 { value} {
    puts “value is $value”
}
```

I am getting below output

```
test1 arg1 arg2

Enter proc test1
Parameters: param1=arg1, param2=arg2, and body
Exit proc test1
wrong # args: should be "puts ?-nonewline? ?channelId? string"
```

Any clue why it is giving error in `puts`

Comment: Why are your quotes in the 2 last `proc`s smart quotes (`“ ”`) and not plain quotes (`" "`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that what you posted is correct, the problem is you're not using the correct quoting character.

Tcl only understands two kinds of quoting:

1. quoting with substitutions: `""`
2. quoting without substitutions: `{}`

The character `“` in tcl will just be treated as any other character such as `a` or `5`.

Note that without quoting, tcl treats the word as a string without spaces. For example, the following examples are all valid strings:

```
this_is_a_valid_string
"this_is_a_valid_string"
{this_is_a_valid_string}
```

Following this simple rule, the following are also valid strings and are all equivalent:

```
“hello
"“hello"
{“hello}
```

So when you ask tcl to execute the following:

```
puts “parameters are $param1 and $param2”
```

it treats it as:

```
puts {“parameters} {are} "$param1" {and} "$param2”"
```

passing 5 arguments to `puts`.

Obviously this would trigger an error since puts expects either one or two arguments.